# В каких книгах можно почитать про потоки в Windows?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, книги

В каких книгах можно почитать про потоки в Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Джонсон М. Харт "Системное программирование в среде Windows" Третье издание

Answer (score 0):

Рихтер и Танненбаум. Windows для профессионалов и Современные операционные системы соответственно

Comment: я имелл ввиду ищё и с конкретными примерами

Comment: Там у Рихетра в книге есть вроде. Например там через потоки реализован WinApi Message Box в котором текст обновляется по таймеру.